# Understanding decompiled source code of a smart contract

Tags: solidity, bsc, bscscan

I decompiled a contract on BSC with [bsc decompiler](https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0xaacb683a934a5e1aee846286049f1a5dd38bdfb9). And I can't understand storage declaration:

```
#
#  Panoramix v4 Oct 2019 
#  Decompiled source of bsc:0x698E165F2897e4daC68671c4cDFf337bbC543767
# 
#  Let's make the world open source 
# 
def storage:
  owner is addr at storage 0
  stor1 is mapping of uint8 at storage 1
  stor2 is uint256 at storage 2
  unknownf45567f7 is array of struct at storage 3
  stor4 is mapping of uint256 at storage 4
  balanceOf is array of uint256 at storage 5
  unknown5320a3d1 is array of uint256 at storage 6
  tokenOfOwnerByIndex is mapping of uint256 at storage 7
  stor8 is mapping of uint256 at storage 8
  unknownf5aa3420Address is addr at storage 9
  unknownb8e3bf64Address is addr at storage 10
  unknown8115ad5dAddress is addr at storage 11
  ownerOf is mapping of struct at storage 12
```

I have never seen like the above in solidity. Is this even correct syntax? Can someone help me understand the above function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Solidity syntax, but I am quite sure this is custom output created by [Panoramix](https://github.com/palkeo/panoramix).